# Проверка актуальной версии мобильного приложения

Tags: react-native, мобильные-приложения, проверка, обновление

Доброго времени суток!

Возник простой вопрос, на который нужен довольно сложный ответ.
Как узнать, есть ли у мобильного приложения ( в данном случае кросплатформенного ) актуальная версия мобильного приложения? Приложение крос. на React Native.

Проще говоря, когда пользователь запускает мобильное приложение, после запуска показывать информационное окно с текстом, "Вышла актуальная версия, обновитесь" как пример.

Как сервер может узнать что, в сторах опубликовано новое мобильное приложение, и отправить информацию об этом в текущую версию мобильного приложения?

Comment: можете реализовать актуальную версию на сервере и при запуске приложения проверять является текущая версия актуальной.

Answer (score 0):

пакет "sp-react-native-in-app-updates"

https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-in-app-updates